# fine-tuning of makebox width

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pst-jtree

I'm writing a slideshow with `beamer`, with various slides containing trees (in the graph-theoretic sense). The talk I'm going to be using this slideshow for discusses how changing the label of a certain vertex can affect the label of another vertex elsewhere in the tree. To do this "before/after" , I'm using `\only<1>{some label}\only<2>{some other label}` in the relevant vertices; see minimal working example at the bottom of this post.

The problem with this example is that the new label is wider than the original one; given that the replacement happens on a vertex at one of the sides of the tree, it affects the width of the entire tree; given that the tree is centered, the transition from the old label to the new one makes the whole tree shift a bit.

To avoid this, I want to enclose the original label in a `\makebox`, and then use the width of the new label as the width of the box. My first idea was to use something like `\makebox[\hphantom{the new label}][c]{old label}`, but that simply inserts a `\phantom` box inside the `\makebox`, rather that declaring the width of the `\makebox`.

Obviously, I can do it the ugly way, i.e., by declaring the width of the `\makebox` in mm or whatever and then try different widths until I find the right one. What I'm looking for here is a more general solution.

```
\documentclass[dvips,11pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-jtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \vfill
    \begin{center}
      \jtree[xunit=3.8em]
      \! = {some label}!a .
      \!a = <left>{some label} ^<right>{some label}!b .
      \!b = <left>{some label} ^<right>{\only<1>{old label}\only<2>{the new label}}!c .
      \!c = <vert>{some label} .
    \endjtree
  \end{center}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make it clear: this is a purely aesthetic issue. The .tex file compiles without problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) offers `\widthof{<stuff>}` which returns the width (as a length) of `<stuff>`. As such you can use:

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvips,11pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-jtree,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \vfill
    \begin{center}
      \jtree[xunit=3.8em]
      \! = {some label}!a .
      \!a = <left>{some label} ^<right>{some label}!b .
      \!b = <left>{some label} ^<right>{\only<1>{\makebox[\widthof{the new label}]{old label}}\only<2>{the new label}}!c .
      \!c = <vert>{some label} .
    \endjtree
  \end{center}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It's also possible, depending on whether or not the width measurement is limited by expansion, to capture the width in a length elsewhere using

```
\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{the new label}
```

and then use `\mywidth` wherever you want to reference the width of `the new label`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with the `eqparbox` package: instead of using a declared width,   `\eqparbox`  is an \mbox that defines a tag which can be used with the subsequent \eqparboxes: all \eqparboxes using this tag will have the same width as the first.

There are also `\eqmakebox`, `\eqframebox`, `\eqsavebox` commands and an `eqminipage` environment.

Demo:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-jtree}
\usepackage{makebox, eqparbox}

\begin{document}

{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{The new label}}

\eqparbox{new}{The new label}

\eqframebox[new]{Old label}

\end{document}
```

[image]